# Почему функция срабатывает сразу независимо от расположения кода

Tags: javascript

Я новичок. И я не могу понять следующее.
Есть код

```
hello('привет');

function hello(argunent)
{
alert (argument)
}
```

Почему я могу вызвать сразу функцию, ведь она ещё как я понимаю не определена и должна находиться после самой функцией?

Comment: А в умных книжках это описано. Почитайте понятие "всплытие функций" неважно в каком месте определена функция она всегда "всплывает" в начало области своей видимости.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Хотелось бы что бы вы дали рекомендации что читать

Comment: Это называется Function Declaration, которая создаются интерпретатором до выполнения кода, поэтому ее можно вызвать до объявления

Comment: следует отметить, что ожидаемое вами правило будет работать в случае такого кода:     ```
    var hello = function(argument) {
      alert (argument)
    }

    hello('привет');
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/function-declaration-expression